# Error when creating new Spring MVC project in IntelliJ: invalid item 'Maven: org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:1.0.0.M2

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 to create a new project with Spring MVC and "Create project from template" checked, I get the error message below in the project structure.

Anyone know why, and whether I should worry about it?

```
Module 'Test': invalid item 'Maven: org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:1.0.0.M2' in the dependencies list
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... What version of Spring is the template project using?

From Spring 3.2 and onwards the spring-test-mvc dependency was merged into spring-test dependency.

So for anything using Spring 3.2 onwards you only need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also, It might be worth looking at the Spring [platform-bom](http://platform.spring.io/platform/)